# PDO - Error with number of bound variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this error when I run the code:

**Error:**

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens - Line: 106

**Code:**

```
$data_cadastro = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");

$query = "INSERT INTO FRETES (VENDA_CLIENTE_ID_CLIENTE, VENDA_ID_VENDA, DT_COLETA, DT_ENTREGA, LINK, TRANSPORTADORA, POSICAO, VALIDA, DT_CADASTRO) 
            VALUES (:id_cliente, :id_venda, ':dt_coleta', ':dt_entrega', ':link', ':transportadora', ':posicao', :validacao, ':dt_cadastro')";
$banco = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

try {
    $banco->execute(
        array(
            ':id_cliente' => $this->id_cliente,
            ':id_venda' => $this->id_venda,
            ':dt_coleta' => $dados['DTcoleta'],
            ':dt_entrega' => $dados['DTentrega'],
            ':link' => $dados['linkFrete'],
            ':transportadora' => $dados['transportadora'],
            ':posicao' => $dados['posicaoFrete'],
            ':validacao' => $dados['validacao'],
            ':dt_cadastro' => $data_cadastro
        )
    );
} catch (PDOException $exception) {
    die("Execução da Query com erro (inserir novo frete): " . $exception->getMessage() . ' - Linha: ' . $exception->getLine());
}
```

Where i wrong?

Comment: You dont need the quotes around the placeholders So `':dt_entrega'` should be `:dt_entrega` Fix all those and the issue shoudl disappear

Comment: The quotes make the placeholders strings, not placeholders. `':dt_coleta', ':dt_entrega', ':link', ':transportadora', ':posicao'` are all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the placeholders

```
$query = "INSERT INTO FRETES 
                (VENDA_CLIENTE_ID_CLIENTE, VENDA_ID_VENDA, DT_COLETA, 
                DT_ENTREGA, LINK, TRANSPORTADORA, POSICAO, VALIDA, DT_CADASTRO) 
        VALUES (:id_cliente, :id_venda, :dt_coleta, :dt_entrega, :link, 
                :transportadora, :posicao, :validacao, :dt_cadastro)";
```